# what is the time complexity of below code fragment?

Tags: algorithm, asymptotic-complexity

Let A[1, …n] be an array storing a bit (1 or 0) at each location, and f(m) is a function whose time complexity is Θ(m). Consider the following program fragment written in a C like language:

```
counter = 0;
for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
{ if a[i] == 1) counter++;
else {f (counter); counter = 0;}
}
```

I am only able to deal with the best case where all the bits are 1 ,hence the time complexity will be Θ(n),but I am having confusion in determining worst case which will occur when all bits are either 0 or more than half of the bits are 0 , issue is the complexity of the function is confusing me ,if I try to ignore it then complexity will be Θ(n) itself ,please guide me in solving this .

Comment: `f(m) is a function whose time complexity is Θ(m)`

So in worst case your code has O(n^2) complexity.

Comment: Please indent your code for readability.

Comment: @TarwirdurTuron It isn't quite that simple because `n` is not the input to the function `f`. In particular, the more often `f` is called, the smaller the average input to `f`.

Comment: Just to clarify, you aren't wrong in saying the code is O(n^2), that is indeed an upper bound. But you can get a tighter bound.

Comment: @JeremyWest In worst case a[i]==0 for each i. And we have `n` calls `f(m)` where `m` from `1` to `n`. If `f(m)` has complexity O(n) - total complexity will be O(1+2+...+n) = O(n*(n+1)/2) ~= O(n^2). UPD: Yes, I missed counter=0. Sorry.

Comment: No, the counter is reset to 0 after each call to f, so you have n calls of f(0), which has linear complexity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sum of all the counters passed to f is at most n, so the total cost in calling f is O(n). That's because f(m) has time complexity Theta(m), which implies cost f(m) < c*m for some c, so one can bound the cost of calling f with inputs m_1, m_2, ..., m_k by c*(m_1 + m_2 + ... + m_k).

There's some work done each time round the loop, so the total cost is also bounded below by a multiple of n. Therefore the total cost is Theta(n).

Comment: Can the downvoter please explain? Is it because they think the answer is O(n^2)?

Comment: It might alleviate confusion if you point out that the linear run time of `f` allows you to bound the total time spent running `f` using the sum of the inputs to `f`. If `f` had non-linear complexity (e.g. Theta(log n) or Theta(n^2)) then the argument wouldn't work without some modification.

Comment: I understood the upper bound part but I am unable to get the lower bound part , say I have half the values as 0 and half as 1 , Have you considered the lower bound omega(n) for the case when all the bits are 1 ?

Comment: Use the same argument for the lower bound. Just switch the inequality.

Comment: You can ignore f to compute the lower bound: each time through the loop, the statement `if a[i]==1` is executed, which is O(1). Therefore the code has at least linear runtime.

Comment: Just last confusion ,In worst case when all the bits will be 0 , so why are we not putting a bound of O(mn) ,i.e. why are we neglecting the complexity of the given function ?

Comment: @RadhaGogia If all the bits are 0, f(0) is called n times, which takes Theta(n) time no matter what the time complexity of f. It's not possible to infer that this is the worst case.

Comment: So then what will be the worst case of this algorithm , I guess it is totally dependent on the function because the for loop will anyways iterate every time for n times so as such we can't predict the worst case of this algorithm since even when all the bits are either 0 or 1 , the code will run for n times